# Docker-compose connection refused from celery

Tags: django, docker, celery, docker-compose

I am running `docker-compose` to bring together django, celery, postgres and rabbitmq, with the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  # PostgreSQL database
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=<XXX>
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<XXX>
      - POSTGRES_DB=<XXX>
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=<XXX>
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=<XXX>
    ports:
      - "5672:5672" 
      - "15672:15672"

  # Django web server
  web:
     build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
     hostname: web
     command: /srv/www/run_web.sh
     volumes:
          - .:/srv/www
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     links:
       - db
       - rabbit
     depends_on:
       - db

   # Celery worker
    worker:
       hostname: celery
       build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
       command: /srv/www/run_celery.sh
       volumes:
           - .:/srv/www
       links:
          - db
          - rabbit
       depends_on:
          - rabbit
```

In one of the Django views I delegate out to a celery task which does some processing and then tries to post the results to another web service:

```
#views.py
@csrf_exempt
def process_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #
        #Processing to retrieve data here
        #

        delegate_celery_task.delay(data)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)

#tasks.py
@app.task
def delegate_celery_task(in_data):
    from extractorService.settings import MASTER_NODE
    import json
    import urllib

    #
    #Some processing on in_data here to give out_data
    # 

    data = {'data': out_data}
    params = json.dumps(data).encode('utf8')

    req = urllib.request.Request('http://%s/api/data/'%(MASTER_NODE), data=params,
              headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

    urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

For now `MASTER_NODE` is simply localhost:8001 where I am running the other web service. The setup runs when I run everything outside of docker. On starting docker though the worker process gives:

`worker_1  | [2016-11-28 12:20:17,527: WARNING/PoolWorker-2] unable to cache TLDs in file /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tldextract/.tld_set: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/
usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tldextract/.tld_set'`

and then on posting to the Django view, the celery worker starts but gives an error on the urlopen call:

`worker_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 368, in trace_task
worker_1  |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 623, in protected_call
worker_1  |     return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
worker_1  |   File "/srv/extractor_django/extractorService/tasks.py", line 25, in extract_entities
worker_1  |     urllib.request.urlopen(req)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
worker_1  |     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 465, in open
worker_1  |     response = self._open(req, data)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 483, in _open
worker_1  |     '_open', req)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
worker_1  |     result = func(*args)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1268, in http_open
worker_1  |     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
worker_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1242, in do_open
worker_1  |     raise URLError(err)
worker_1  | urllib.error.URLError:`

The celery config in settings.py is:

```
RABBIT_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get('RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP', 'rabbit')
if RABBIT_HOSTNAME.startswith('tcp://'):
    RABBIT_HOSTNAME = RABBIT_HOSTNAME.split('//')[1]

BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('BROKER_URL', '')
if not BROKER_URL:
    BROKER_URL = 'amqp://{user}:{password}@{hostname}'.format(
        user=os.environ.get('RABBIT_ENV_USER', '<XXX>'),
        password=os.environ.get('RABBIT_ENV_RABBITMQ_PASS', '<XXX>'),
        hostname=RABBIT_HOSTNAME)

BROKER_HEARTBEAT = '?heartbeat=30'
if not BROKER_URL.endswith(BROKER_HEARTBEAT):
BROKER_URL += BROKER_HEARTBEAT

BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
Queue('default', Exchange('default'), routing_key='default'),)

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = False
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 600

CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1000
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be fixed?

Comment: where is your celery trying to post? it should do requests to your rabbit container instead of localhost.

Comment: It is trying to post to an external site running outside of docker. In development this is the localhost of my machine on port 8001 on which another web service is running, but in production a site running on AWS.

Comment: I was more concerned what is your backend config for celery tasks you're creating?

Comment: Rabbitmq is used as a queue and I don't store the result - I simply post it to another service. I've added the celery config from settings.py

Comment: Ok, so I just noticed that you say your master node is localhost:8001, that will not work from docker unless you run your service within same docker container which I assume you don't, you probably want to change this address to your docker bridge address

Comment: will putting docker0 here work or is there some IP I should use?

Comment: there should be ip you can use I think, it's usually 172.x.x.x like 172.17.42.1, also make sure you service listens for connections from bridge device

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the version of Celery, but from the post date I can guess it is v4.

I just had similar problem due to updating Celery from v3.1 to v4 and according to this [tutorial](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) it was needed to change `BROKER_URL` to `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in the `settings.py`